# Can I set a timer for pages to be published?

Tags: pages, publish, draft

I have a page that's in draft mode right now because I want to publish this on a particular day (sometime this week). Is there a way that I can set a timer/countdown for this page to automatically be published on a day that I choose?

I don't want to manually publish this page as I want this up at 12:00 AM and I don't want to wake up in the middle of the just to do that...

Is there some sort of script I can run to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No script of function necessary. It's actually built into WordPress. Simply go to your page to edit and on the right hand side you should see a widget labeled *Publish*.

On the third line down, you will see an *Edit* button and you can set the date and time on when you want the page to be shown:

[image: Publish]

Comment: Wow, I feel silly now... Didn't even realized that. Thanks you for pointing that out in the picture. This will save me the headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Please have in mind that this feature sometimes doesn't work if you use some caching plugins. Especially caching plugins that offer static page HDD-Cache.

WordPress uses a HTTP-Cron to publish planned posts (and to do some other stuff). This cron (wp-cron.php) is executed everytime a user visits your site. If you use a page cache, the WordPress-Machinery doesn't start up because the user is directly redirected to a static html file "outside" of the WordPress. This behaviour "breaks" the HTTP-Cron of WordPress.

Alternatively you can access your wp-cron with your server crontab:

```
*/10 * * * * curl http://example.com/wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This ensures that the wp-cron runs without any problems when you use page cache.

Comment: Hm, very interesting point you mad. I wouldn't have known. I'll be sure to make sure my cron is running to post correctly.